# Clang is not able to find Input Files

Tags: windows, dll, clang, shared-libraries, gn

I am getting this error while creating executable file:

```
[1/2] clang++ -shared  -o ./SampleDll_check.dll @SampleDll_check.dll.rsp
FAILED: SampleDll_check.dll SampleDll_check.lib
clang++ -shared  -o ./SampleDll_check.dll @SampleDll_check.dll.rsp
clang++: error: no input files
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Please provide any hint what is wrong?

Comment: I doubt `clang` driver does understand `@style` arguments. Use `clang-cl` or do not use `@args`.

Comment: @arrowd No, It didn't worked.